# Is it possible to convert SPI to UART without a microcontroller?

Tags: serial, spi, uart, converter

I was wondering about converting SPI to UART only in that direction, not the other way around, without using any microcontroller or bridge.

If synchronous can be seen as a particular case of asynchronous communication, wouldn't be somehow possible to make the Rx just read the input? (At least in the case it was an uninterrupted flow of bits.)

Of course, the baudrate should be matched... but are there any other limitations I'm missing?

Cheers!

Comment: Provided the goal is a simple bytewise conversion, this is actually a better fit for a state machine than for a stored program computer.  However, MCU's are more readily available in small units of functionality than programmable logic fabric, and more people are familiar with efficiently developing for them.  Things may be simplest if the output baud rate is faster than the input by more than the factor of transmitted word length over payload bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the SPI bit rate matches the UART bit rate you want to generate, it can be done.

The SPI data stream needs to be carefully constructed:

- SPI data is normally MSB-first, but UART data is normally LSB-first, so you'll need to reverse the bit order in each of the data bytes.
- UART data contains a start bit and a stop bit bracketing each byte, so for each 8-bit data byte you want to transmit, you need to put (at least) 10 bits into the SPI data stream. One easy (but inefficient) way to do this would be to alternate data bytes with bytes of `11111110`.

Comment: Nice! What if I cannot change the way the SPI data stream is constructed? Would it still be possible to reconstruct the information after UART?

Comment: No. If you can't change the SPI data stream, then you need to construct a SPI slave device that can interpret it as-is. By far, the easiest way to do this is to use a small microcontroller. Why are you ruling this out?

Comment: I am not allowed to modify the device that generates the SPI data stream. I was hoping to avoid the need of an additional microcontroller because of space and simplicity... but I cannot imagine other alternatives! Looks like it's gonna be a micro then! Any suggestions? It would be nice to avoid designing a board and soldering stuff, but also without using Arduino-like boards.

Comment: What type of physical device are you looking for? What kind of connections between devices? Will it fit inside the original enclosure or be its own animal?

Comment: The device will receive a continuous stream of SPI data and output it to UART. UART is connected to the user interface, so it can be used both ways (full duplex), to eventually configure the device we are discussing if necessary. Size is an issue, it should be small (an Arduino Micro is already too large) and should support a baud rate of 115200. Energy consumption needs to be reasonable low, but that's secondary. Besides that, I cannot think of any further limitation...

Comment: "I was hoping to avoid the need of an additional microcontroller because of space and simplicity.." are you saying you don't want things small and simple? Because that is what a microcontroller solution would look like. Arduino is not a microcontroller, it is a development board that contains, amongst other things, a microcontroller (and headers and connectors and voltage regulator supply and USB interface and ... . @Fran Probably an 8-pin ATtiny would be perfect for the job.

Comment: With simplicity and space I mean not adding anything, that's why the main question!! I know Arduino is not just the micro, but I cannot imaging using a micro alone... usually you'll need a board, and connectors, and stuff!! Anyway, I'll check the tiny Arduino! Thanks!

Comment: correct: I'll check the ATtiny

Comment: Additional constraint: the SPI data must be clocked out at exactly the right moments. For 'normal' SPI this is not a requirement, so probably a normal SPI source does not pay any attention to this.

Comment: In your original question, you said this was a one-way transfer. Now you're saying that it's two-way. This means that there is some higher-level protocol by which the SPI master determines whether there is incoming data. You are going to have to implement that protocol, assuming you have adequate documentation on it.

Comment: No, let me clarify... I only need to convert from SPI to UART, it is a one-way process. The SPI master only generates output and gets no input. If I happened to use an intermediate device to make this process happen, then I could use UART in both directions to configure this device, since the UART side can be modify according to my needs. But data coming from UART doesn't need to be forwarded to the SPI. Actually, it shouldn't, since I don't know what kind of consequences it might have.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: Are you talking about flow control? The OP has already stated that it's a "continuous stream" of SPI data, so it's a given that the UART data rate needs to be high enough to eliminate any concerns about flow control.

Comment: With UART the bit cell boundaries must be accurately spaced in time, because the receiver samples based on time alone. With SPI the only requirement is that the data has to change at some moment between the active clock edges. There is no requirement on the exact timing of those data changes (or of the clock edges). Hence it is not impossible that some SPI data stream could be used to fake a UART data stream, but is far from guaranteed. (No, this has nothing to do with flow control.)

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: I thought it was clear that we have gone way beyond the idea of using the SPI hardware to generate a UART signal -- the OP has stated that he cannot modify the SPI master in any way.

Comment: Not from reading your answer, that was what I was commenting on.

Answer (score 0):

There are custom ICs for example this one from NXP:
http://www.nxp.com/products/interface_and_connectivity/bridges/i2c_spi_slave_to_uart_irda_gpio_bridges/series/SC16IS740_750_760.html

They probably have an MCU hidden inside, for buffering and arbitration.

Comment: Thanks! I have one of those, but the device is configured using SPI and my main limitation is that the SPI is generated by a system which I cannot modify in any way.

Comment: By the way! Do you know if it would be possible to setup one of those via UART? That would solve my problem :-)